# Why my recyclerview item clones when i call edit item in adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, clone

```
public void editMessage(Message editedMessage,int position) {
    this.messagesItemList.set(position, new AdapterItem(editedMessage));
    notifyItemChanged(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, messagesItemList.size());
}

@Override
public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
    Message message = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
    messageAdapter.editMessage(message, messageAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
    //messageAdapter.change(messageAdapter.getMessagesCount() - 1);
}
```

My RecyclerView clones item when I try to call edit message.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in one line

```
h.setIsRecyclable(false);
```